# border radius not work for fa-stack in font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I add fontawesome icon with square this worked for me:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-twitter">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-gplus">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-stack-1x {
    color:white;
    border-radius:0;
}
.fa-square{
    border-radius:0;
}
.icon-facebook {
   color:#3b5998;
}

.icon-twitter {
    color:#00aced;
}

.icon-gplus{
    color:#dd4b39;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I need to show square without border radius and I add `border-radius:0;` for class `.fa-square` But font awesome not work without border radius.

how do can i fix this ?

DEMO [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nfz9sucn/87/)

Comment: They look fine in the JSFiddle.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In action i see border radius in square. i need to remove border radius from square.

Comment: That comment wasn't clear, can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @OfirBaruch: please see this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/ClDlm.jpg . line two is without bordr radius i need to this .

Comment: @Mark: please see image: i.stack.imgur.com/ClDlm.jpg

Comment: It's hard to fix something which we can't reproduce the same problem.  I don't see how you get the second row while I'm getting results just like the first row in the image

Comment: I believe it's not related to `border-radius` since it's an image with "rounded corners" and not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned the "square" behind the icon is actually a font icon applied to .fa-square:before in the css.

Unfortunately the Font Awesome set at this time does not contain a true square.

However they do have an icon in their set with much harder corners called the "stop" icon (in the video player icon group).  You can substitute this for the "square" in your css to get a much better square stack by doing this. It does make a very slight radius corner, but at small sizes it's hardly noticable:

```
.fa-square:before {
  content: "\f04d";
}
```

"\f04d" is the CSS content value for the stop icon in Font Awesome.

**List of CSS content values for Fontawesome Icons**

http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

**Results**

[Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSYWw.png)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

fa-square:before{content:"\f0c8"} is going to cause an issue. You can fix it by removing that class. Then overriding the border-radius for each of the fa-stack-1x icons.

[image]

[image]

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-twitter">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-gplus">
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.fa-stack-1x {
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color:white;
}
.icon-facebook>.fa-stack-1x  {
    background-color:#3b5998;
}
.icon-twitter>.fa-stack-1x  {
    background-color:#00aced;
}
.icon-gplus>.fa-stack-1x {
    background-color:#dd4b39;
}
```

For squares just change the border-radius's to 0px; in the above CSS

Answer (score 0):

I looked into font-awesome.min.css and found this line: `fa-square:before{content:"\f0c8"}` I believe that means you are using `\f0c8` to draw the square. That means it is a character from awesome font and you can't change it by `border-radius`.
You can read about this icon at
http://www.utf8icons.com/character/61640/UTF-8-character